# A legal payment for a product, but obtaining it at illegal place

Tags: united-states, copyright, online-piracy

I'm in the US, and I was looking for the legal ways to watch English Premier League. Unfortunately, most of the legal streaming services do not support Linux, and I have a Linux. Technically, I could watch on my phone with a much smaller screen, because Android is supported. Also, I could install windows or android emulator on my system and use a browser from there to watch games. But all of these are complicated, hence the question:

> Can I pay legally for a service to watch a game, and then use illegal websites to watch it? Is it legal?

Probably I am not gonna do that, but what is the answer?

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11820/is-it-illegal-to-download-cracked-software-one-has-purchased, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13927/is-it-piracy-to-download-a-copy-of-a-book-that-my-university-has, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23912/is-it-piracy-to-obtain-software-you-purchased-in-an-alternate-way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the nature of online distribution, "watching" a show involves copying, so you need permission from the copyright holder to make those copies. You get permission indirectly, when you access a show via a legal licensee who has permission to distribute. A pirate site has no permission, therefore you cannot legally sub-license the show, and in so doing, you infringe copyright. The issue is not whether you "paid for it", it is whether you have obtained proper permission. Under copyright law, a rights holder can simply arbitrarily deny you permission to copy the work.